# Settings limits for individual handles in noUISlider

Tags: nouislider

I'm liking noUISlider, but I can't figure out how to set limits on individual handles for a two handle slider.

I've tried this approach, which works but messes up the `mouseDown` event a little:

```
$("#slider").on({
        slide: function(){

            var upper_val = $("#slider").val()[1];

            if ($("#slider").val()[0] <= min) {
                $("#slider").val([min, upper_val]);
            }

            if ($("#slider").val()[0] >= max) {
                $("#slider").val([max, upper_val]);
            }
        }
    });
```

There has to be a cleaner way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The slide event fires on *every* slide, so performance will suffer if you keep calling `.val()`. You could use the `set` event, like in [this example](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-soft-limits), so that a handle 'bounces back' if it crosses your threshold.